# Why can't DOMParser parse this XML?

Tags: xml, domparser

I am making a call to the Google Map API and get a response which seems like basic XML.

Attempting to Parse the XML using DOMParser is failing, with some sort of parsing error, but I don't understand why.

The entire code:

```
    let result: ILatitudeLongitude = { latitude: 0, longitude: 0 };

    let axiosConfig = {
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/xhtml+xml' }
    };
    let url = 'http://some-server/api/GoogleMaps/GetGoogleAPI?fullAddress=123 some st, suburb, state, 1000';
    let response = await axios.get(url, this.axiosConfig);
    if (response && response.data) {
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        // response.data looks like this: "<lat>-34.9441798</lat><lng>138.5997218</lng>"
        let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(response.data, "application/xhtml+xml");
        if (xmlDoc) {
            try {
                let lng = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('lng')[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
                let lat = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('lat')[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;

                if (lat && lng) {
                    result.latitude = +lat;
                    result.latitude = +lng;
                }
            } catch (e) {
                errorHandler.handle(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
```

Attempting to retrieve the 'lng' element just fails:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('lng')
```

=> 0 results

If I inspect the elements of the xmlDoc via this statement:

```
xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('*')
```

I see that it parses the 'lat' element, but then it gives me a parsererror element. Digging into the parsererror element, I find:

"error on line 1 at column 61: Extra content at the end of the document"

Which is confusing because the XML string doesn't even have 61 characters...its 46 characters in length.

Any ideas on how I could successfully parse this little snippet of XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XML document must have exactly one root element, there can't be two elements at the top level: [XML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#dt-root).